# Object doesn't support property or method 'find' - where to find suitable polyfill script?

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer, ecmascript-6, polyfills

I have a web app (AngularJS, WebAPI, MVC...), I use ES6 new features.
Everything works like a charm in Chrome.
The problem is with IE (we have IE 11 at work).
IE doesnt like few things, such as:

**Object doesn't support property or method 'find'** and other ES6 functions.

I have heard of polyfill scrips that I can add to my app so that it will work in IE as well.

**I dont know what polyfill script I need and there to find it.**

Can someone assist? Thanks.

Comment: Have you even searched the web for "es6 polyfill"?

Answer (score 3):

for polyfill script use es6 shim:
https://github.com/paulmillr/es6-shim

if your object is array
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

```
if (!Array.prototype.find) {
  Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'find', {
  value: function(predicate) {
 // 1. Let O be ? ToObject(this value).
  if (this == null) {
    throw new TypeError('"this" is null or not defined');
  }

  var o = Object(this);

  // 2. Let len be ? ToLength(? Get(O, "length")).
  var len = o.length >>> 0;

  // 3. If IsCallable(predicate) is false, throw a TypeError exception.
  if (typeof predicate !== 'function') {
    throw new TypeError('predicate must be a function');
  }

  // 4. If thisArg was supplied, let T be thisArg; else let T be undefined.
  var thisArg = arguments[1];

  // 5. Let k be 0.
  var k = 0;

  // 6. Repeat, while k < len
  while (k < len) {
    // a. Let Pk be ! ToString(k).
    // b. Let kValue be ? Get(O, Pk).
    // c. Let testResult be ToBoolean(? Call(predicate, T, « kValue, k, O »)).
    // d. If testResult is true, return kValue.
    var kValue = o[k];
    if (predicate.call(thisArg, kValue, k, o)) {
      return kValue;
    }
    // e. Increase k by 1.
    k++;
  }

  // 7. Return undefined.
  return undefined;
}
});
}
```

Comment: Yes, I added this exact script and it works!
However, I was looking for script file that contains all polyfills, not just for find function. Some all-in-1 polyfill script that I can just include.

Comment: try Modernizr, https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills

Comment: I added Modernizer via nuget Package Manager, it doesnt work, same exceptions